# Mot incertain, peut-être mal prononcé

Tags: prononciation

Dans l'interview suivante, à [2h52m30s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQb1e2Bvv-A&t=10350s), on peut entendre ce qui suit.

> … de Churchill ils avaient avancé leur grande offensive …tout ça on était assez au courant hein … leur grande offensive parce que les officiers [XXX] … étaient en train … risquaient de prendre une pilée à l'ouest …

Est-ce que quelqu'un comprendrait le mot ou les deux mots remplacés par « [XXX] » ?

Comment: Il me semble qu'il essaie de dire: occidentaux, mais n'arrive pas à le dire. Je n'entends pas du tout le mot officiers. Mais, il est possible que je me trompe complètement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il dit "Les sovietiques avaient lancé, à la demande de Churchill, ils avaient avancé leur grande offensive, ça, on est assez au courant, hein, la grande offensive parce que les occidentaux étaient en train... (il se reprend) risquaient de prendre un pilée à l'ouest"

Comment: Merci ! Je n'ai aucun doute, c'est bien « les occidentaux » ; je me demande comment je n'entendais pas, ça me parait suffisamment clair maintenant.